# Bash replacing content INLINE using a WGET and CAT commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on some kind of version control for a specific software (Bash script.)
When a new version releases, the code should be updated to the latest release, I have figured this out but I seem stuck and can't make the replacement inline.

```
#First we download the source code with wget, it returns a text with the new code
wget www.example.com/sourcecode | cat . > $0
```

How can I redirect that output (text / script) to the current script who's executing it and replace it.
Note `$0` gives us the location of the current script. So the `cat` command, **just should replace the new text coming from `wget` to the current script.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused, so I can try to guess your needs.

Are you asking how to capture the output of the commmand you posted?

If yes, the solution is:

```sh
source_file_content=$(wget -O - http://www.example.com/sourcecode)

# Do anything with ${source_file_content}
```

Let me know if it is right for you.